# Changing href attribute on click event and then revert it back immediately?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, settimeout

How can I change the "href" attribute af a link (A) element with JavaScript in its onclick event handler, and revert back to the original href after the click happened? So when second click happens the original href url should open.

My approach is the following using setTimeout: 
    `enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/6u4zvvy9/

Can it be solved without setTimeout?

Comment: Smells like fake links! "Do you want to visit the link? See an advertisement and try again!"

Comment: Yes, exactly! For my blog.

Answer (score 0):

so maybe just record the original href:

```
elem = document.getElementById("google");
elem.newhref = "http://yahoo.com"
elem.originhref = "";
elem.onclick = function () {
    if(elem.originhref){
        elem.href = elem.originhref;
        elem.onClick=null;
    }else{
        elem.originhref = elem.href;
        elem.href = elem.newhref;
    }
};
```

By the way, I think using timeout is quite a nice solution.

Comment: In fact I don't want to alternately iterate them, but using yahoo on the first click, and the original google at every further clicks.